# ADD Image overlay to ffmpeg video stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg and want to add an HUD to the video stream, so a few questions.

1. What file do I need to edit.
2. What do I need to do to achieve this.

Thanks in advance. Also I am VERY new to all of this, I will need instructions step by step

I saw other questions saying to add this: `ffmpeg -n -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1[v];[v][1]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" -movflags +faststart tmb/video.mp4`

But I dont know where to put it, i entered it in the terminal and got this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -n -i video.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1[v];[v][1]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" -movflags +faststart tmb/video.mp4
ffmpeg version N-86215-gb5228e4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-ldl
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavcodec     57. 96.101 / 57. 96.101
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 90.100 /  6. 90.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
video.mp4: No such file or directory
```

I dont understand what i am supposed to do with the video.mp4?

HERE IS THE SCRIPT THAT SENDS THE VIDEO.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import re
import os
import time
import urllib2
import platform
import json
import sys
import base64
import random


import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='robot control')
parser.add_argument('camera_id')
parser.add_argument('video_device_number', default=0, type=int)
parser.add_argument('--kbps', default=450, type=int)
parser.add_argument('--brightness', default=75, type=int, help='camera brightness')
parser.add_argument('--contrast', default=75, type=int, help='camera contrast')
parser.add_argument('--saturation', default=15, type=int, help='camera saturation')
parser.add_argument('--rotate180', default=False, type=bool, help='rotate image 180 degrees')
parser.add_argument('--env', default="prod")



args = parser.parse_args()



server = "runmyrobot.com"
#server = "52.52.213.92"


from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

# enable raspicam driver in case a raspicam is being used
os.system("sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2")


if args.env == "dev":
    print "using dev port 8122"
    port = 8122
elif args.env == "prod":
    print "using prod port 8022"
    port = 8022
else:
    print "invalid environment"
    sys.exit(0)


print "initializing socket io"
print "server:", server
print "port:", port
socketIO = SocketIO(server, port, LoggingNamespace)
print "finished initializing socket io"

#ffmpeg -f qtkit -i 0 -f mpeg1video -b 400k -r 30 -s 320x240 http://52.8.81.124:8082/hello/320/240/


def onHandleCameraCommand(*args):
    #thread.start_new_thread(handle_command, args)
    print args


socketIO.on('command_to_camera', onHandleCameraCommand)


def onHandleTakeSnapshotCommand(*args):
    print "taking snapshot"
    inputDeviceID = streamProcessDict['device_answer']
    snapShot(platform.system(), inputDeviceID)
    with open ("snapshot.jpg", 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    print "emit"

    socketIO.emit('snapshot', {'image':base64.b64encode(data)})

socketIO.on('take_snapshot_command', onHandleTakeSnapshotCommand)


def randomSleep():
    """A short wait is good for quick recovery, but sometimes a longer delay is needed or it will just keep trying and failing short intervals, like because the system thinks the port is still in use and every retry makes the system think it's still in use. So, this has a high likelihood of picking a short interval, but will pick a long one sometimes."""

    timeToWait = random.choice((0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 5))
    print "sleeping", timeToWait
    time.sleep(timeToWait)



def getVideoPort():


    url = 'http://%s/get_video_port/%s' % (server, cameraIDAnswer)


    for retryNumber in range(2000):
        try:
            print "GET", url
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            break
        except:
            print "could not open url ", url
            time.sleep(2)

    return json.loads(response)['mpeg_stream_port']

def getAudioPort():


    url = 'http://%s/get_audio_port/%s' % (server, cameraIDAnswer)


    for retryNumber in range(2000):
        try:
            print "GET", url
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            break
        except:
            print "could not open url ", url
            time.sleep(2)

    return json.loads(response)['audio_stream_port']



def runFfmpeg(commandLine):

    print commandLine
    ffmpegProcess = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(commandLine))
    print "command started"

    return ffmpegProcess



def handleDarwin(deviceNumber, videoPort, audioPort):


    p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true", "-f", "qtkit", "-i", "dummy"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    out, err = p.communicate()

    print err

    deviceAnswer = raw_input("Enter the number of the camera device for your robot from the list above: ")
    commandLine = 'ffmpeg -f qtkit -i %s -f mpeg1video -b 400k -r 30 -s 320x240 http://%s:%s/hello/320/240/' % (deviceAnswer, server, videoPort)

    process = runFfmpeg(commandLine)

    return {'process': process, 'device_answer': deviceAnswer}


def handleLinux(deviceNumber, videoPort, audioPort):

    print "sleeping to give the camera time to start working"
    randomSleep()
    print "finished sleeping"


    #p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true", "-f", "qtkit", "-i", "dummy"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    #out, err = p.communicate()
    #print err


    os.system("v4l2-ctl -c brightness={brightness} -c contrast={contrast} -c saturation={saturation}".format(brightness=args.brightness,
                                                                                                             contrast=args.contrast,
                                                                                                             saturation=args.saturation))


    if deviceNumber is None:
        deviceAnswer = raw_input("Enter the number of the camera device for your robot: ")
    else:
        deviceAnswer = str(deviceNumber)


    #commandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video%s -f mpeg1video -b 1k -r 20 http://runmyrobot.com:%s/hello/320/240/' % (deviceAnswer, videoPort)
    #commandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video%s -f mpeg1video -b 150k -r 20 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (deviceAnswer, server, videoPort)
    # For new JSMpeg
    #commandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video%s -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v 250k -bf 0 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (deviceAnswer, server, videoPort) # ClawDaddy
    #commandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -s 1280x720 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video%s -f mpeg1video -b 1k -r 20 http://runmyrobot.com:%s/hello/1280/720/' % (deviceAnswer, videoPort)


    if args.rotate180:
        rotationOption = "-vf transpose=2,transpose=2"
    else:
        rotationOption = ""

    # video with audio
    videoCommandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video%s %s -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v %dk -bf 0 -muxdelay 0.001 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (deviceAnswer, rotationOption, args.kbps, server, videoPort)
    audioCommandLine = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -f alsa -ar 44100 -ac 1 -i hw:1 -f mpegts -codec:a mp2 -b:a 32k -muxdelay 0.001 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (server, audioPort)


    print videoCommandLine
    print audioCommandLine

    videoProcess = runFfmpeg(videoCommandLine)
    audioProcess = runFfmpeg(audioCommandLine)

    return {'video_process': videoProcess, 'audioProcess': audioProcess, 'device_answer': deviceAnswer}



def handleWindows(deviceNumber, videoPort):

    p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true", "-f", "dshow", "-i", "dummy"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


    out, err = p.communicate() 
    lines = err.split('\n')

    count = 0

    devices = []

    for line in lines:

        #if "]  \"" in line:
        #    print "line:", line

        m = re.search('.*\\"(.*)\\"', line)
        if m != None:
            #print line
            if m.group(1)[0:1] != '@':
                print count, m.group(1)
                devices.append(m.group(1))
                count += 1


    if deviceNumber is None:
        deviceAnswer = raw_input("Enter the number of the camera device for your robot from the list above: ")
    else:
        deviceAnswer = str(deviceNumber)

    device = devices[int(deviceAnswer)]
    commandLine = 'ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f dshow -i video="%s" -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -b 200k -r 20 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (device, server, videoPort)


    process = runFfmpeg(commandLine)

    return {'process': process, 'device_answer': device}



def handleWindowsScreenCapture(deviceNumber, videoPort):

    p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-list_devices", "true", "-f", "dshow", "-i", "dummy"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


    out, err = p.communicate()

    lines = err.split('\n')

    count = 0

    devices = []

    for line in lines:

        #if "]  \"" in line:
        #    print "line:", line

        m = re.search('.*\\"(.*)\\"', line)
        if m != None:
            #print line
            if m.group(1)[0:1] != '@':
                print count, m.group(1)
                devices.append(m.group(1))
                count += 1


    if deviceNumber is None:
        deviceAnswer = raw_input("Enter the number of the camera device for your robot from the list above: ")
    else:
        deviceAnswer = str(deviceNumber)



    device = devices[int(deviceAnswer)]
    commandLine = 'ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vf "scale=640:480" -f mpeg1video -b 50k -r 20 http://%s:%s/hello/640/480/' % (server, videoPort)

    print "command line:", commandLine

    process = runFfmpeg(commandLine)

    return {'process': process, 'device_answer': device}




def snapShot(operatingSystem, inputDeviceID, filename="snapshot.jpg"):    

    try:
        os.remove('snapshot.jpg')
    except:
        print "did not remove file"

    commandLineDict = {
        'Darwin': 'ffmpeg -y -f qtkit -i %s -vframes 1 %s' % (inputDeviceID, filename),
        'Linux': '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video%s -vframes 1 -q:v 1000 -vf scale=320:240 %s' % (inputDeviceID, filename),
        'Windows': 'ffmpeg -y -s 320x240 -f dshow -i video="%s" -vframes 1 %s' % (inputDeviceID, filename)}

    print commandLineDict[operatingSystem]
    os.system(commandLineDict[operatingSystem])



def startVideoCapture():

    videoPort = getVideoPort()
    audioPort = getAudioPort()
    print "video port:", videoPort
    print "audio port:", audioPort

    #if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    #    deviceNumber = sys.argv[2]
    #else:
    #    deviceNumber = None
    deviceNumber = args.video_device_number

    result = None
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        result = handleDarwin(deviceNumber, videoPort, audioPort)
    elif platform.system() == 'Linux':
        result = handleLinux(deviceNumber, videoPort, audioPort)
    elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
        #result = handleWindowsScreenCapture(deviceNumber, videoPort)
        result = handleWindows(deviceNumber, videoPort, audioPort)
    else:
        print "unknown platform", platform.system()

    return result


def timeInMilliseconds():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))



def main():

    print "main"

    streamProcessDict = None


    twitterSnapCount = 0

    while True:



        socketIO.emit('send_video_status', {'send_video_process_exists': True,
                                            'camera_id':cameraIDAnswer})


        if streamProcessDict is not None:
            print "stopping previously running ffmpeg (needs to happen if this is not the first iteration)"
            streamProcessDict['process'].kill()

        print "starting process just to get device result" # this should be a separate function so you don't have to do this
        streamProcessDict = startVideoCapture()
        inputDeviceID = streamProcessDict['device_answer']
        print "stopping video capture"
        streamProcessDict['process'].kill()

        #print "sleeping"
        #time.sleep(3)
        #frameCount = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        videoWithSnapshots = False
        while videoWithSnapshots:

            frameCount = timeInMilliseconds()

            print "taking single frame image"
            snapShot(platform.system(), inputDeviceID, filename="single_frame_image.jpg")

            with open ("single_frame_image.jpg", 'rb') as f:

                # every so many frames, post a snapshot to twitter
                #if frameCount % 450 == 0:
                if frameCount % 6000 == 0:
                        data = f.read()
                        print "emit"
                        socketIO.emit('snapshot', {'frame_count':frameCount, 'image':base64.b64encode(data)})
                data = f.read()

            print "emit"
            socketIO.emit('single_frame_image', {'frame_count':frameCount, 'image':base64.b64encode(data)})
            time.sleep(0)

            #frameCount += 1


        if False:
         if platform.system() != 'Windows':
            print "taking snapshot"
            snapShot(platform.system(), inputDeviceID)
            with open ("snapshot.jpg", 'rb') as f:
                data = f.read()
            print "emit"

            # skip sending the first image because it's mostly black, maybe completely black
            #todo: should find out why this black image happens
            if twitterSnapCount > 0:
                socketIO.emit('snapshot', {'image':base64.b64encode(data)})




        print "starting video capture"
        streamProcessDict = startVideoCapture()


        # This loop counts out a delay that occurs between twitter snapshots.
        # Every 50 seconds, it kills and restarts ffmpeg.
        # Every 40 seconds, it sends a signal to the server indicating status of processes.
        period = 2*60*60 # period in seconds between snaps
        for count in range(period):
            time.sleep(1)

            if count % 20 == 0:
                socketIO.emit('send_video_status', {'send_video_process_exists': True,
                                                    'camera_id':cameraIDAnswer})

            if count % 40 == 30:
                print "stopping video capture just in case it has reached a state where it's looping forever, not sending video, and not dying as a process, which can happen"
                streamProcessDict['video_process'].kill()
                streamProcessDict['audio_process'].kill()
                time.sleep(1)

            if count % 80 == 75:
                print "send status about this process and its child process ffmpeg"
                ffmpegProcessExists = streamProcessDict['process'].poll() is None
                socketIO.emit('send_video_status', {'send_video_process_exists': True,
                                                    'ffmpeg_process_exists': ffmpegProcessExists,
                                                    'camera_id':cameraIDAnswer})

            #if count % 190 == 180:
            #    print "reboot system in case the webcam is not working"
            #    os.system("sudo reboot")

            # if the video stream process dies, restart it
            if streamProcessDict['video_process'].poll() is not None or streamProcessDict['audio_process'].poll():
                # wait before trying to start ffmpeg
                print "ffmpeg process is dead, waiting before trying to restart"
                randomSleep()
                streamProcessDict = startVideoCapture()

        twitterSnapCount += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":


    #if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #    cameraIDAnswer = sys.argv[1]
    #else:
    #    cameraIDAnswer = raw_input("Enter the Camera ID for your robot, you can get it by pointing a browser to the runmyrobot server %s: " % server)

    cameraIDAnswer = args.camera_id


    main()
```

ERROR:

```
ffmpeg -n -f mpegts -i http://54.183.232.63:12221 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setsar=sar=1[v];[v][1]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" -movflags +faststart tmb/video.mp4
ffmpeg version N-86215-gb5228e4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-ldl
  libavutil      55. 63.100 / 55. 63.100
  libavcodec     57. 96.101 / 57. 96.101
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 90.100 /  6. 90.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[mpegts @ 0x1a57390] Could not detect TS packet size, defaulting to non-FEC/DVHS
http://54.183.232.63:12221: could not find codec parameters
```

Comment: The video stream and HUD - what are their filenames?

Comment: havent made the hud yet, but for the purpose of the question lets just call it hud.png

Comment: as far as the video stream I am not sure, It was made by someone else, I am posting the script that sends the video

Comment: `-i video.mp4` should be replaced with `-f mpegts -i http://server:port` (if sender is on Win or Linux) or `-f mpeg1video -i http://server:port` for Darwin. where server and port should be replaced with their respective values.

Comment: its on raspian which i believe is linux. Ill give it a try

Comment: at the end where it says "+faststart tmb/video.mp4" what should that be replaced by?

Comment: Leave the `+faststart` as is. `tmp/video.mp4` is output path and filename. So whatever you need.

Comment: I tried it and got an error I posted it above

Comment: Add `-probesize 20M -analyzeduration 20M` before the video input. Probably some junk data upfront.

Comment: before the video input, sorry i am a big noob??????

Comment: `-f mpegts -probesize 20M -analyzeduration 20M -i http://server:port`

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Leave out the `-f mpegts`

Comment: http://runmyrobot.com:12221: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: seems to be a lost cause

Comment: Is there a betterway, I mean, can i just take the video that is being pulled from my camera rather than the video on the server

Comment: As per the script, the video is being streamed, not saved on disk. You can try saving it to file and inputting that.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?